# How do I get website chat bubble out from behind footer?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, salesforce, chatbot

The site I am working on https://ihcsuspension.com/ has a chat feature I am trying to implement to get chats into Salesforce. It is currently hiding behind the footer but I for the life of me can not find a way to bring it forward or pull the footer back. This is a WordPress build. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. I have tired pushing back the footer via z-index to no avail.

This is the code adding the chat bubble in the footer.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
gform.initializeOnLoaded( function() {jQuery(document).trigger('gform_post_render', [1, 1]);gform.utils.trigger({ event: 'gform/postRender', native: false, data: { formId: 1, currentPage: 1 } });} );
</script>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/menu/fab.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var initESW = function(gslbBaseURL) {
        // Required if you want labels in a language that’s different from your user’s context.
        //embedded_svc.menu.settings.language = ''; //For example, enter 'en' or 'en-US'

        embedded_svc.menu.init(
            'https://ihcsuspension.my.salesforce.com',
            'https://d.la3-c1-ia6.salesforceliveagent.com/chat',
            gslbBaseURL,
            '00DHs000000QTLN',
            'IHC_Suspension'
        );
    };

    if (!window.embedded_svc || !window.embedded_svc.menu) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.setAttribute('src', 'https://ihcsuspension.my.salesforce.com/embeddedservice/menu/fab.min.js');
        s.onload = function() {
            initESW(null);
        };
        document.body.appendChild(s);
    } else {
        initESW('https://service.force.com');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Like I mentioned in the previous post you made with this question, have you considered [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: Sorry tried to rephrase my question a little better. Also as previously stated. Yes, I tried z-index and it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set position to relative/absolute/[etc.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.php) while trying pushing it with z-index?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did set it to a relative while I was working as they were set to static by default.